# Does <?php echo $PHP_SELF?> No Work In PHP 5.x?

Tags: php

I know that with PHP 4.1 they introduced the concept of super globals, which I do not entirely understand, but I had the following code working with PHP 4.3.x (or something close to that), and recently updated to PHP 5.2.4, and now the info doesn't seem to want to get posted to my database. It just returns me to the same page I was trying to submit from.

```
if ($submit) {
mysql_select_db("ibmclub",$db);
$sql = "INSERT INTO april_floral (image) VALUES ('$image')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
header("location:confirm.php");
} else {
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF?>">
<form guts>
<?php
}
?>
```

You get the gist. Having problems escaping the brackets to get the code to show up.

So, is there s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's moved to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. register_globals is deprecated and will be completely removed in a future version of PHP. You'd better update your code to not rely on it.

Comment: I made the following change : `<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">` but it still doesn't work. Do I need to enable register_globals in my php.ini file?

Comment: It should work, but try adding a semi-colon at the end of the PHP call. Also check your HTML source to see what got generated.

Comment: With or without semi-colon, I get the same results from the following HTML code : `<form method="post" action="/photo/voting_floral.php">`. Is there anything I need to change in my `if($submit)` statement?

Comment: What value would you like to have in the action attribute? What's wrong?

Comment: The problem is that it's not submitting the user's choice to the database. It should record the choice and then direct the user to the confirm.php page.

Comment: Where do you set the value on $submit and $image? Do you use register_globals here as well? They are in the $_POST array when register_globals is disabled.

Comment: So, I ended up enabling global variables, but just for a week, because I have some time sensitive online voting that needs to get done. I'll come back to debug, and turn off globals, after that's done. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

it could be that your `register_globals` setting was turned off with the upgrade you did.
The correct way to use it is `<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>`